# Database still doesn't show Identity columns after Add-migration and Update-Database Done

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I created a Web API with classical data layer access class `ApplicationContext`

```
public class ApplicationContext: DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Thing> Things{ get; set; }
        
    }
```

**Then** i successfully added a frist Initial migration and update-database for adding columns in database.

**After** i had to change my `ApplicationContext : DbContext` to `ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext` in order to get default identity tables form EmtityFramworkCore.Identity into my Database.

**So** i executed again a `Add-Migration AddedIdentityTables` for a new migration with IdentityData and i got them into a new Migration, after `Update-Database` i successfully got Identity columns in last Snapshot of Database im Migration folder, **but there were literally no identity columns in the database**

What am i doing whron?

Comment: Try to refresh the database.

Comment: "I tried so hard and get so far, but in the end id doesn's even work :)"

Comment: Try to specify the identity  user and its idetntity column explicitly:
`ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>>`